# How to create an dynamic filter in excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on excel and do not have much experience in implementing dynamic functionality.

I am trying to program the excel sheet in such a way that it filters the values based on the value entered in the particular cell (say 4rth col and 1st row).

```
Col1: Client_Name
Col2: Title
Col3: Balance
```

So, its like a search on Col1 based on value entered by user in the 4rth col and 1st row. Is this possible using excel? I have not worked on VBA, but if that is the solution then I would like to go ahead and use it.. Any reference would help me..

I would like to have it all dynamic so that end user only has to type in the value at the cell located at 4rth col & 1st row and tab out to see the results... Other then that, the end user should not be forced to click anywhere else to get the desired results...

Comment: `Other then that, the end user should not be forced to click anywhere else to get the desired results` - only VBA can help you

Comment: If you want to leverage off the `Worksheet_Change` or `Worksheet_SelectionChange` events, you will have to write some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add following code to the `Sheet Module` corresponding the sheet with your data (see picture below). Every time value in `D1` changed - filter for columns `A:C` would be reapplied:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'If changed any other cell do nothing
    If Target.Address <> "$D$1" Then Exit Sub

    AutoFilterMode = False
    'Field:=1 means that filter applies to third column of A1:C1 - i.e. column A
    Range("A1:C1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & Target
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: OK, I have entered this code into the Sheet code. Do I now have to save it as a macro enabled excel workbook?

Comment: And is there a way to debug this?.. Because, if i try to set a debug point and hit the debug (play) button, then, it opens up a Macro window. However, there is no macro in it so the 'Run' button is disabled..

Comment: After setting a debug point just edit your value in the `D1` cell. It starts the debugger

Comment: I wanted to debug it as it is not achieving the functionality, I will sit and try to debug it to make it work.

Comment: Should it be: Range("A1:C1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & Target ? This way worked.. Just asking..

Comment: Depends on what column you want to filter. `Range("A1:C1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & Target` applies filter for column A, `Field:=2` for column B, `Field:=3` for column C

Comment: Cool thanks.. I can see that the other rows are hidden, I know thats what the filter is supposed to do. But, is it also possible to hide the other rows?

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean by `is it also possible to hide the other rows`?

Comment: The other rows must not be visible.. Is this possible.

Comment: Try to add this line in the end of macro `Range("A:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Hidden = True`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46070/discussion-between-nachiket-kamat-and-simoco)