# VBA - Speed of Hiding/Unhiding Row as a Worksheet Event

Tags: excel, vba

I'm struggling with the speed at which the following VBA code executes.

The goal of this code is to activate whenever "C4" changes, and then scan column "R" for the value 'Y'. If there's a 'Y', then it hides the row, and if not, it unhides the row. The code works, it's just not speedy - for 500 rows, it can take 30 or more seconds every time I change the value of "C4".

Does anyone have any suggestions to improve the speed at which this code executes? Or another method of accomplishing this?

Thanks for taking a look.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim L As Long
Dim r As Range

L = Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C4")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each r In Range("R2:R" & L)
        If r.Value = "Y" Then
            Rows(r.Row).Hidden = True
        Else
            Rows(r.Row).Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
End If

End Sub
```

In attempting to apply the suggestion below - use Union() - I have come up with the below, not working, code. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim L As Long
Dim r As Range
Dim RowsToHide As Range
Dim RowsToUnhide As Range

L = Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C4")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each r In Range("R2:R" & L)
        If r.Value = "Y" Then
            RowsToHide = Union(RowsToHide, r.Row)
        Else
            RowsToUnhide = Union(RowsToUnhide, r.Row)
        End If
    Next
End If

RowsToHide.Hidden = True
RowsToUnhide.Hidden = False

End Sub
```

Comment: @JvdV Sorry, I'm new to stackoverflow. Should I have posted this somewhere else? Are you able to provide any code or resources to go to get ideas for how to merge ranges and then hide/unhide at once? You're right I do agree that should improve the speed.

Comment: Typically SO is more for helping others troubleshoot errors in code, but the community will decide if this question is off topic.  Also, I would look into using the `Application.Union` function for grouping all the rows that need to be hidden as that may also help with performance.

Comment: I recommend looking into `AutoFilter` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349872/how-to-create-an-dynamic-filter-in-excel

Comment: @valantic questions like this asking for some level of code review are _not_ off topic on SO.  So please don't feel you must move it to CR.  But if you do post it on CR, be sure to follow their rules.

Comment: @chrisneilsen's answer below is the best solution. Thank you everyone for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several techniques that will help speed this up

- Writing to `.Hidden` is much slower than reading it.  So check if the row is already hidden or showing before setting `Hidden`
- Collect the rows to Hide or Show into a range (Union) and Hide/Show tehm in one go.

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range
    Dim rngCheck As Range
    Dim rngHide As Range, rngShow As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C1")) Is Nothing Then
        Set rngCheck = Me.Range(Me.Cells(1, "R"), Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp))
        For Each r In rngCheck.Cells
            If r.Value2 = "Y" Then
                If Not r.EntireRow.Hidden Then
                    If rngHide Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngHide = r.EntireRow
                    Else
                        Set rngHide = Union(rngHide, r.EntireRow)
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                If r.EntireRow.Hidden Then
                    If rngShow Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngShow = r.EntireRow
                    Else
                        Set rngShow = Union(rngShow, r.EntireRow)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If

    If Not rngHide Is Nothing Then
        rngHide.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    If Not rngShow Is Nothing Then
        rngShow.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely the direction I think I need to be going in. However, I'm not sure what's going on. I pasted this code (changing the intersect range to "C4" which is the cell that triggers the Y/N to populate in column R) but nothing seems to execute. No rows hidden/unhidden. Are you able to help troubleshoot?

Comment: I was able to get the majority of the code to work as a module subroutine, I seem to just be having trouble getting the code to execute from the worksheet event. Good news though - the code completes nearly instantaneously!!

Comment: You need to put the code in the relevant worksheet module, or if you put it in a std module change the `Me`s to a valid worksheet reference

Comment: Yeah, I put the code in relevant worksheet module, but it never seems to be executing. In troubleshooting, I threw it into a standard module and changed the 'Me's to valid worksheet references and it worked - very quickly. i'd prefer it in the worksheet module though executing from the worksheet event, I just can't figure out why it's not executing from changing "C4".

Comment: How does C4 value change?   If it's a formula then that won't trigger the Change event

Comment: It worked with the code I had originally posted, which seems to be using the same logic to trigger the event - that's what's confusing. It is _not_ a formula, but it _is_ a drop-down list. This then populates the Y/N in column "R", which are formulas.

Comment: Another possibility, did you happen to try Application.EnableEvents=False as per the other answers?

Comment: No, that doesn't exist in my code. I've even tried removing the 'If Not Intersect' piece entirely (which should then execute with every change to the sheet, correct?) but nothing executes.

Comment: What I mean is if you _ever_ ran Application.EnableEvents = False and for some reason didn't run Application.EnableEvents = True later then event handling will be disabled, it doesn't matter if that snippet is in the current code or not.  Just to be sure try running Application.EnableEvents = True , it won't do any harm if it's already true

Comment: That was 100% it!! Thank you so much Chris. Your answer should definitely be the top on this page, but it won't let me vote since I have less than 15 reputation.

Comment: FYI you can [accept it by clicking the tick](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Accepted! Thanks again Chris.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `Application.EnableEvents = False` at the beginning of the code then turning back to true will help, Also using `Applciation.ScreenUpdating = False` should help as well.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim L As Long
Dim r As Range

Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

L = Cells(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C4")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each r In Range("R2:R" & L)
        If r.Value = "Y" Then
            Rows(r.Row).Hidden = True
        Else
            Rows(r.Row).Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I actually added these just after I posted my question! It does help - but not to the degree I'd like. It still takes 20ish seconds to run. Thank you for your contribution!

Comment: I would also look up using the `Application.Union` function as that will combine all the rows that need to be hidden into one group then hide them.